# Fluid bake crashing at high resolution divisions

Tags: fluid-simulation

Having the resolution set to anything higher than 128 is a guaranteed crash, the higher the value the sooner the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, I had the same issue with smoke simulations. In Blender 2.90 and above the OpenVDB volume format comes with Advanced Settings. Here you can choose Compression Volumes "None", "Blosc" and "Zip". The default value is "Blosc".

After switching to "Zip", the baking works without any problems. "None" works, too. Only "Blosc" makes all my machines crash, no matter if laptop or my two PCs.

You can try this, but I have to admit that someone else here had similar issues like you with fluid simulations and it didn't help. But as you describe it, your fluid simulation behaves exactly like my smoke simulation.